# Xtend tip: how do I access a static method within a Java interface inner class?

Tags: xtend

```
// java
interface MyInterface { 
    class MyInnerClass {            
        public static final String myInnerStaticMethod() {
            return "myInnerStaticMethod";
        }       
    }
}
```

How can I call this from an Xtend method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// xtend
def test() {
    MyInterface$MyInnerClass::myInnerStaticMethod
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually, the latest version of Xtend (>2.4.1) uses much nicer syntax.

```
// xtend
def test() {
  MyInterface.MyInnerClass.myInnerStaticMethod
}
```